# backbone fetch not updating the model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using a requirejs with backbone. The script runs without error but *model*.fetch() does not update the model. The two files for Backbone.js are:-

In main.js I have

```
'use strict';


require(['pageElements'],function(pageElements){

    $( document ).ready(function() {

       var country = new pageElements.country();

       country.fetch({

         success: function(e){

               console.log(country.get('areaLevelZeroID')); // returns undefined

            }

        });

    });

});
```

In pageElements.js I have

```
define(function() {

    var country = Backbone.Model.extend({

        url : 'resources/js/backBoneSandBox/countries.php',

        parse: function(data){

            newData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(newData.areaLevelZeroID);  // returns 1
            return data; 


            }

     });

return ( country );

});
```

Where the parse function is returning the correct value but not updating the model.

resources/js/backBoneSandBox/countries.php is tested and returns the jSON String

```
{"areaLevelZeroID":"1","areaLevelZeroName":"Afghanistan"}
```

I must be missing something really simple but I just can't see what. Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Why are you specifying your own `parse` function? Your `.php` returns JSON already, you're re-interpreting it as JSON in your `parse` function - why? Can you just remove the `parse` all together and try again?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Still no difference.

Comment: What happens if you use, in your `success` function, this piece of code: `console.log(e.toJSON());`?

Comment: returns the jSON Object {{"areaLevelZeroID":"1","areaLevelZeroName":"Afghanistan"}: Object}

Comment: Ok, so the first argument to the function, in your case it's called `e`, is the model itself. When you call `toJSON()` on that object, you get expected output. What's the result of `e.get('areaLevelZeroID');`?

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: just `return newData;` in your parse function

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I was returning data not newData

Comment: You shouldn't need to parse JSON as the received data is already parsed. The `parse` function is used when the wanted data is nested into the received object. In your case, it looks like your backend returns a string which contains JSON instead of returning JSON directly.

Comment: yes, `parse` function just pass resp along to `set`, but it assumes resp to be JSON already.

Answer (score 0):

In general flow is `fetch - parse - set - success handler`. 
In your case you receive string response from the server, so you have to parse it to JSON, before calling `set` on the model. Thats why, you had to `return newData;`